# best way to strip a leading 0 from numerical representation of a month?

Tags: php

So I have a PHP variable w/ a (possibly the current, possibly not) month in it in the form of ##. If the month is less then October I want to take the leading 0 out. Is there a good and simple way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cast it as an integer:

```
<?php
  $month = '01';
  echo (int) $month; // prints 1
?>
```

Comment: you can do this but not sure about this.  Use j instead of d and n instead of m:

Answer (score 8):

You can use the built in date function to do this, should look something like

```
<?php
date('n/d/Y',strtotime($dateVariable));
?>
```

You can use n instead of m to display the month without the leading zeros.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php for more information about date formatting.

Comment: your solution will not work because  'n' is used for non zero month. if you want to get non zero form date then you will have to use  'j'

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

  $month = '05'; // May
  $month *= 1;

  echo $month; 

?>
```

Output

```
5
```

Comment: Are you multiplying the date by 1 here?

Answer (score 1):

```
$today_mem = date("j.n");
```

Use `j` instead of `d` and `n` instead of m:

source:: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like:

```
<?php
      $month = intval(Date('m'));
      echo $month; // prints int value
    ?>
```